How test @NotNull on a controller?
I have this controller :
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Validated
@RestController
public class ControllerFoo {

    public String getFoo(@NotNull String foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
        return foo;
    }
}

I want to test @NotNull, see my test :
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestControllerFooTests {

    @Test
    void testControllerFooKONotNull() {
        ControllerFoo controllerFoo = new ControllerFoo();
        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> controllerFoo.getFoo(null));
    }
}

Actually my test is KO because controllerFoo.getFoo(null), do not throw anything.
What should I do ?
I want to test my parameter to be not null. It doesn't work and I need to
understand why.
Thanks in advance!
